# What happens when assigned null to String object?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand what happens to a string when null is assigned to it.
So, I have a `String str = new String("abc");` It uses some space in memory.
When `str` is assigned `null`, i.e `str = null`, what happens to the memory that was used to create `"abc"` . Does it still use space in memory?

Comment: You're assigning null to a *variable*, not an object. The object remains in memory until it is garbage collected.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so yes, it wastes space until the GC kicks in

Comment: That said, if you used a string literal like `"..."` or interned the string, it will still remain in Javas internal string cache.

Comment: When you use the obsolete constructor like `new String("abc")`, you have already *two* string objects, the one created via `"abc"` and the copy created via `new String(…)`. The string `"abc"` was never referenced by a variable, but still is the one that will likely live far longer than the one created with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Java is garbage collected. The memory allocated for the string will be freed at a feature point in time determined by the garbage collector. See [Java Garbage Collection Basics](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) for details.

**Update**: as commenters pointed out [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) *might* prevent the string from getting garbage collected. Details depend on many things like the scope of the reference, JVM and Java version.

Comment: Note that Java has a string cache. If the string was created using a literal or interned, it will remain in the cache. Just a minor note though.